# Derivative of a Decreasing Function

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Show that if $C(K,T)$ is a differentiable function of $K$, then the derivative of $C(K,T)$ must lie between between minus one and zero.

I have to use the following theorem:

1. $C(K,T)$ is a decreasing function of $K$,
2. $C(K,T)$ is a (Lipschitz) continuous function of K with Lipschitz constant $Z(T)$
3. $C(K,T)$ is a convex function of $K$.

Basically what I have so far is that by taking the derivative of $C(K,T)$ having the Lipschitz constant of $Z(T)$ as a result, this would be negative because it is a decreasing function of $K$. Hence the lower bound for the derivative would be $-1$.